# Health and Liveness probe for Azure Web Jobs

Tags: azure-webjobs, health-check, readinessprobe

We are setting up a time-triggered background job that needs to connect to multiple resources, like SFTP, Azure Blob, Azure SQL, etc. The idea is to leverage Azure's Web Job capability to host the service on Azure's App Service.

We have a requirement that we need to host heathiness and readiness APIs just like the one's for containerized solutions. First, of all is it recommended to have those for background running jobs as they will only be running for a certain time.

And am absolutely unsure if this can be done, read a couple of articles online but i do not see anything that directs me to the answer that i am seeking.

Comment: did you get a chance to look into [this](https://pacodelacruz.io/monitoring-azure-webjobs-health-with-application-insights)

Comment: Hope this  reference [helps](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/load-balancer/manage-probes-how-to.md)

Comment: cannot find any doc related Liveness probe for Azure Web Jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Azure Web Jobs can be configured to have healthiness and readiness APIs.
- Azure Container Apps are based on Kubernetes health probes and can be set up using either TCP or HTTP(S) exclusively.
- The probes supported by Container Apps include Liveness, Readiness, and Startup.
- The Liveness probe reports the overall health.
- To enable Health check, browse to the Azure portal and select your App Service app. Under Monitoring, select Health check. Select Enable and provide a valid URL path on your application, such as /health or /api/health.
- Create a [Azure WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create).

[image]

- Run the test cases using this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON).

[image]

- Create a Azure WebJobs Health with [Application Insights](https://pacodelacruz.io/monitoring-azure-webjobs-health-with-application-insights) with `https://{webapp-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/{webjob-name}`.

  [image]
- The Monitor Azure WebJobs status with Azure Application [Insights](https://dotnetthoughts.net/monitor-azure-webjobs-status-with-application-insights/)  are displayed in the image below. Thank @pacodelacruz

[image]

- For more details refer this Monitoring Azure WebJobs Health with [Application Insights](https://pacodelacruz.io/monitoring-azure-webjobs-health-with-application-insights) .

Comment: Thanks for all the input @Sampath.
I realized after going through a lot of docs, that the ones you shared lead to the same conclusion. The ask from the team is to have a readiness and healthiness endpoint within the project so that as and when required this could just be migrated to a Kubernetes cluster. With WebJob I can possibly configure web hooks to expose those but that is too much of a hassle, rather in the apathy of any solution that I could get, I had o convert the project to an API service. Now, my service can run in the background as is whereas with the web libs, i can do te necessar